# Simple PHP script stops executing with no error while executing mssql_query function

Tags: php, error-handling

I have this  simple PHP script, which is calling a MSSQL db procedure:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

mssql_connect('server', 'user', 'pass');
mssql_select_db('dbname');

if(mssql_query(' exec dbo.SomeProcedure '))
    echo "OK\n";
else
    echo "FAIL\n";
```

When trying to call the script from web browser, I receive a "connection reset" message. When trying to call it from command line, no *echo* command is executed. It just fails on line with *mssql_query* call.

No error message is displayed, or saved to php error log (defined in virtualhost). The strange thing is, that if I call another procedure within the same PHP script, it works fine. And if I call the same procedure (under the same user) directly in database, it also works fine (no error raised).

No additional error handling is implemented, the mentioned piece of code is the whole content of my script.

Can someone, please, give me a advice, how to debug/find out, what is gone wrong?

***PHP version***: PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze25 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)
***MSSQL driver***: freetds

Comment: I think it wants to tell you to STOP using **mysql_*** an start using **PDO** or **mysqli_*** instead..

Comment: He isnt using `mysql` but `mssql`

Comment: Try storing the connection result and tell its `var_dump`

Comment: @DarshanJain My bad, it's still early today..

Comment: @DarshanJain  it will not pass the line with `mssql_query`, so there is no way to `var_dump` the result, script simply doesn´t get there.

Comment: I am saying to do this : `$link =
mssql_connect('server', 'user', 'pass');var_dump($link);`

Comment: @DarshanJain Sorry for misunderstanding, the tip you mentioned works, it now prints the error. Although I do not understand how, if `var_dump` is before the `mssql_query` call, but nevermind, thanks for the solution!

Comment: So the error was in connection ? Right ?

Comment: That's why you should use something like `mssql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server");`

Answer (score 0):

> It just fails on line with mssql_query call.

This means either error is before if or i the call .

> I receive a "connection reset" message.

Probably means that there is an error in connection like database name or pass, etc . So make sure the parameters in connection establishing line are correct

Comment: There wasn´t an error in connection, but in mssql_query when working with datetime field: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48908